# IE8 bug - borders and width on floated image

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

It's weird that I have this bug on IE8 and not on IE7, where it shows up fine:

http://www.axiscirugiadecolumna.com/

I'm using a wordpress plugin for the shadow+ribbon (I hardcoded the ribbon inside the shadow plugin). The border is simply css but on IE8 the **right border** won't show up and I just don't know why.

My html is the following:

```
<div class="alignright" style="overflow:hidden;display:table;line-height:0;text-align:center;width:453px;">
   <div class="ribboncontainer">
       <div class="ribbon"></div>
       <img height="297" width="453" style="padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important; max-width:100% !important;" alt="" src="http://www.axiscirugiadecolumna.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/foto1.png" title="foto1" class=" size-full wp-image-143 shadow_curl">
       <br><img style="margin:0 !important;height:10px;width:100%;-moz-opacity:.75;opacity:.75;" class="shadow_img" src="http://www.axiscirugiadecolumna.com/wp-content/plugins/shadows/shadow_curl.png">
   </div>
</div>
```

This is after the plugin is applied. The inline styles are applied by the plugin.

And my css:

```
.alignright, .aligncenter, .alignleft {
   margin: 5px;
   padding-right: 5px;
   float: right;
 }
 .ribbon {
   background-image: url("ribbon.png");
   bottom: 21px;
   height: 40px;
   position: absolute;
   right: -5px;
   width: 154px;
   z-index: 888;
 }
 .ribboncontainer {
    position: relative;
 }
 .shadow_curl {
    border: 6px solid #BAD5BC;/*Right border is missing in IE*/
  }
```

I think the issue persists even if I get rid of the ribbon classes and divs.

Comment: Can you post actual code? This is a community, once your code is fixed or if your website was to ever disappear, future visitors to this question will have no idea what was going on.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I thought about that, I should have done it. I wasn't being lazy or anything, will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that

```
max-width: 100%;
```

style.css (line 894)
img.size-auto, img.size-full, img.size-large, img.size-medium, .attachment img

Comment: Check out there is a max-width:100% !important added inline

Comment: No, I deleted it from everywhere and still nothing :/

Comment: oops max-width:100% !important is still there 

'<img width="453" height="297" title="foto1" class=" size-full wp-image-143 shadow_curl" style="padding-bottom: 0px !important; margin: 0px; padding-left: 0px !important; padding-right: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important;" alt="" src="http://www.axiscirugiadecolumna.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/foto1.png" complete="complete"/>'

also in img.size-full style.css

Comment: Yeah I put it back in case it broke something else but tried without it before manually.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is because IE8 (I also tested your page on IE7) - and both does not support a CSS rule "box-shadow", in your file style.css (line 171).
If you insist to use a drop shadow (as I assume), you should use a transparent png/gif file for these browsers. Keep in mind that IE6 does not support native png files, so it's better to use gif.

Comment: it's not a box-shadow issue, it's the border. The shadow is there for modern browsers and I don't care if it dissapears on IE. The shadow under the images is an actual image.